# How to reload cached trigger types in SmartTarget web app?

Tags: smarttarget

In a SmartTarget web application, trigger types are loaded when the first request is made and put in the ADF to enable the SmartTarget API to map ADF claims to trigger types.

If a new trigger type is added, then we currently need to restart our web application to pick it up and map it from the ADF.

While adding a new trigger type is not a particularly frequent event, it would be good to be able to trigger a reload of triggers in some other way than an application restart - is this possible some way?

Answer (score 2):

The cartridge caches the list in memory, so clearing the claim won't be enough. It will just put the cached list back into the ADF on the next request.

So I think your choices are either to live with the current situation, or write your own version of the cartridge with a more sophisticated cache strategy. Getting the list of triggers is actually pretty simple, as all of the work is in the API.